# AWS Data Pipeline authorization issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, amazon-data-pipeline

I am try to setup a scheduled activity to start and stop ec2 instances. My activities fail giving me following error :

> A client error (UnauthorizedOperation) occurred when calling the
>   StartInstances operation:You are not authorized to perform this
>   operation. Encoded authorization failure message:....

My cli activity is sth like this:

```
  aws ec2 describe-instances  --region us-west-2 --filter "Name=tag:auto-start,Values=yes" "Name=instance-state-name,Values=stopped" --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId]' --output text |xargs aws ec2 start-instances  --region us-west-2  --instance-i
```

Do I need to provide my access/secret keys as additional arguments ? As I have limited access, I cannot update data pipeline policies. However I am able to start and stop instances using aws cli tools.

Comment: is your cli command invoked from datapipeline?

Comment: @Tom yes that is cliActivity in Datapipline

Comment: so you need to specify an IAM role to attach to your datapipeline instances, with the correct rights

Comment: I think that is defined and attached e.g ResourceRole: `DataPipeLineDefaultResource` and `DataPipeLineDefaultRole`

Comment: mmh weird, I guess you have the correct IAM rights in policies attached to these roles? but if you want to schedule an activity, I think AWS lambda service is more convenient and cost efficient.

Comment: I dont have access to these role definitions, I ll ask my Admin if they are needed

Comment: can you provide any reference to lambda service for scheduling EC2 instances ? thanks

Comment: AWS scheduled events: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html, then use an sdk (python, java or node.js) to make your cli call. e.g in python: http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/migrationec2.html#launching-new-instances

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether you are using Lambda or DataPipeline, you need to understand the IAM roles and policies associated with them. To solve your issue, all you have to do is add `StartInstances` privilege to `DataPipeLineDefaultResource` role. The default policy is read only and does not have the privilege to start an instance.

**Recommended policy:**

```
{
     "Version": "2012-10-17",
     "Statement": [
          {
               "Effect": "Allow",
               "Action": [
                    "s3:*",
                    "ec2:Describe*",
                    "ec2:Start*",
                    "ec2:RunInstances",
                    "ec2:Stop*",
                    "datapipeline:*",
                    "cloudwatch:*"
               ],
               "Resource": [
                    "*"
               ]
          }
     ]
}
```

Have your IAM admin create a new policy that allows one to start an instance. AWS DataPipeline document has the required info. Then attach that IAM policy to `DataPipeLineDefaultResource` role and your problem is solved. Once you solve this issue, you can think about using Lambda or not.

Answer (score 1):

I am writing an answer as it turns my proposal needs some details.

For scheduling those kind of things, I recommend using lambda as it is more cost effective and straightforward.

AWS lambda now supports [scheduled events](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html), and you can then put your cli calls using an sdk (currently supported languages are python, node.js and java).

e.g a quick lambda function to start instance would look like below (not tested):

```
import boto3
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ec2.create_instances(ImageId='<ami-image-id>', MinCount=1, MaxCount=5)
```

then you just need to schedule this lambda function (cron like system). Please also take care to attach the correct IAM role / rights.
boto3 documentation is [here](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/migrationec2.html)

Comment: Thanks again. What do you say about cost effectiveness for running two services lambda and SNS ?

Comment: It all depends on your usage. With lambda you get 1 million requests per month for free, and you pay for the memory used during  the execution of the lambda (cheap enough though). lambda pricing: https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/pricing/. With SNS, it depends what you want to publish. sns pricing https://aws.amazon.com/sns/pricing/